# Ediciones que empeoran la pregunta

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Últimamente me han estado llegando 'ediciones' de un usuario a diferentes preguntas, las cuales a mi parecer tienen etiquetas que no corresponden a la pregunta o al tema tratado, en otras ocasiones modifica la pegunta original agregando 'Buenos días', entre otras, no le tomé importancia pero estoy viendo que esas ediciones se están incrementando, aquí un ejemplo:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20415

Es una pregunta que hice hace mucho y le quiere modificar añadiendo la etiqueta **`javascript`**, cosa que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.
Aquí otras 'ediciones' sugeridas:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20400
https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20397

Pongo esto en Meta como ejemplo para futuros usuarios que obtengan el privilegio de editar preguntas, no cometan estas malas costumbres.

Comment: He revisado muchas ediciones de un usuario, que han ido incrementado bastante desde ayer, y todas las ediciones son de etiquetado las cuales concuerdan con la pregunta o bien empeoran el entendimiento,

Comment: Gracias por hacer mención de esto. He notado lo mismo, y se vuelve fastidioso de tener que revertir los cambios constantemente. Justamente hace poco abrí un reporte pidiendo atención de los moderadores al respecto, tanto por lo de las etiquetas superfluas e incorrectas, como por lo de los que parecen estar aprobando los cambios de forma ciega.

Comment: "Performance is a feature". A veces dos usuarios presentan una edición al mismo tiempo, una mejor que la otra, y la que "prevalesce" es la no tan buena.

Comment: EMHO esto es porque hay usuarios tratando de obtener medallas por editar X publicaciones, su interés no es el de mejorar el contenido o realizar correcciones, hacen ediciones superfluas y en muchos casos añaden etiquetas que no tienen relación con la pregunta.

Comment: Relacionado: [Ediciones sugeridas de etiquetas irrelevantes](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/832/127)

Answer (score 1):

- Si están bien etiquetadas, aprobar.
- Si además hay que hacerle alguna mejora, aprobar y editar.
- Si están mal etiquetadas, rechazar.

Tal usuario a veces pone bien las etiquetas, otras veces no. También depende de la opinión del revisor, no siempre se puede decir, esta pregunta definitivamente necesita esta etiqueta.

Con respecto a esta pregunta:

[Evitar registrar duplicados en base de datos con Codeigniter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7211/evitar-registrar-duplicados-en-base-de-datos-con-codeigniter)

De hecho se ve que en el título figura [base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos), pero no usa [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Rechazarla como lo hizo Mariano, es lo correcto.

Comment: El problema es que hay usuarios que las aceptan, en el caso de mi pregunta, aceptaron esa edición y en  mi pregunta jamás hago mención de _JavaScript_ solo es _Php_.

Comment: En realidad, ahora que lo veo con más detalle, creo que en realidad debería haber rechazado como que "causa daño". Probablemente me dejé llevar porque venía de votar por rechazarle otras tantas ediciones que sí eran superfluas.

Comment: @Mariano Creo que hay que tener criterio propio, aveces esas ediciones pueden servir, otras no... No creo que haya que rechazar siempre... Yo estuve pocas horas, la verdad no sé si era tan molesto el usuario.

Comment: @ArtEze Molesto no, jamás diría eso de alguien que está aportando al sitio (independientemente de si opino que el contenido está bien o mal). Creo que está hace poco en SOes y hay algunos conceptos con los que se irá familiarizando en el tiempo. Obviamente **[no considero que haya que rechazar siempre](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/832/ediciones-sugeridas-de-etiquetas-irrelevantes?answertab=votes#comment1915_833)**, sólo que en este caso, en las que me tocó revisar, consideré que sí había que rechazar a la gran mayoría.